# Stitching two Confirmation Numbers on United

Tags: united-airlines

My wife and I are flying to India from America. She is SFO-EWR-BOM-EWR-ORD-SFO and I am flying ORD-EWR-BOM-EWR-ORD. 
Each of us have booked our tickets separately (we couldn't do it together because of different itineraries).

Now, is there a way to "stitch" our tickets together so we have one confirmation number?

The reason I want to do that is:

1. We are flying the EWR-BOM-EWR-ORD sections together. In case there are any cancellations or re-bookings or whatever, both of us would have the same change.
2. We have made sure that we have adjacent seats. We want it so that either both of us get upgraded, or neither.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you can't merge two confirmation numbers.  However, you can call United and ask them to "link" your reservations.  This means adding a note to both bookings pointing to the other, which any human making changes will *hopefully* notice — not a guarantee by any means, but better than nothing.